# How do I get the name of the host (based on ip)?

Tags: ip, hostname

I am not going to disclose the public IP address here , but is there a way on to get the name of the hosting PC / Server .
Thanks

Comment: An IP may serve many hosts.

Comment: Not always helpful, but sometimes googling for the IP will list sites that track and store domain/IP associations; or the occasional cached whois. This information can be stale after sometime, but its a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to do so:

https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

Just input the IP address and it will find a reverse DNS entry (if one exists).

Comment: Only if there's a valid PTR record. 151.101.1.69 (one of StackOverflow's IPs) returns nothing there, for example.

Comment: you can use dig or host for this as well: `dig -x [addr]` ...or `host [addr]`

Answer (score 0):

under linux: "host " returns the primary domain name, if any reverse exist... there is also a "whois " command, returns info about the network block of the ip, so in an ideal situation you get the host's provider and contact info (anyway whois is not part of a default linux install nowadays).